# How to close batch file after react app is closed

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, batch-file, cmd

I have a react application and I start it with the following `.bat` file:

```bash
cd..
cd projects
cd material
cd server

npm run dev
```

When the script runs, it opens cmd, and runs my app, which shows up in chrome.

I searched the whole day, but I didn't find anything for killing the program and closing the batch file by closing the browser.

Is there any way to do this, at all?

Comment: You can kill the process using `PowerShell`.

Comment: @NorioYamamoto - `taskkill` is also a batch command; there's no need to bring a second language into this. They'd also have to use `tasklist | find chrome.exe` to monitor the state of the browser.

Comment: @SomethingDark I don't know if I clear my question but i try here ,
when i click the .bat file the process on cmd start and run the app on chrome browser after few sec, but when I close the browser process is still running .
is there any way to force the cmd to close when I close the browser?

Comment: As a side note, the first four lines you showed could be just one, ```cd ..\projects\material\server```.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try? Just put it last line on your bat file.

```
exit
```

Comment: first thanks for your answer. yes i did try this but no its not work for me, after i run the program i want the cmd closed just when i close the app preview on browser(when i exit the browser)